# Solving heat equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: differential

I am solving the heat equation in spherical coordinates.

$$\frac{\ 1}{\alpha}\frac{\delta T}{\delta t}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\delta}{\delta r}(r^2\frac{\delta T}{\delta r})=\frac{\delta^2 T}{\delta r^2}+ \frac{2}{r} \frac{\delta T}{\delta r}$$

Inicial condition CI: T(r,0)=Ti

Boundary condition 1, r=R:
$$\frac{-k\delta T}{\delta r}=h(T(R,t)-Tinf)$$

Boundary condition 2, r=0:

$$\frac{\delta T}{\delta r}=0$$

$$T(r,t) = X(r)*G(t)$$

Substituting in the equation I got:
$$\frac{\ 1}{\ R}(\frac{\delta^2 T}{\delta r^2}+ \frac{2}{r} \frac{\delta T}{\delta r})=\frac{\ 1}{\alpha G}\frac{\delta G}{\delta t}= -\lambda^2 $$

I already solved the temporal part:
$$G(t)=A \ exp(-\lambda^2 \alpha t)$$

But I have problems to solve the spacial part:

$$R''+\frac{\ 2}{\ r}R'+R\lambda^2=0$$

I have been reading about it, but this part has been solved using the Euler-Cauchy equation and implying other assumptions which are not possible here.

How do I proceed? I'm just taking the differential equations course, so I'm not too much into the topic. I would thank so much your help.